# else statement does not work when (document.exists) is not true "firestore"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to loop throw an array of objects and check if the data in each object exists in the database then preform a specific task if the data exists and another task if the data does not exist in the database. However, the `else` statement  does not get executed when the data is not available in the database and the code stops at the line before the if statement.
note : the if statement works  well when `document.exists` is true the problem only occurs when the data does not exist.

```
      result_array.forEach((doc)=>{
      console.log(doc.id)
      db.collection("users").doc(auth.user.uid).collection("basket").where( "id" , "==" ,doc.id ).get()
     .then((docs) => {
        docs.forEach(document=>{
          if (document.exists) {
            console.log("Document data:", document.data());
            document.ref.update({
              "quantity": document.data().quantity + doc.quantity,
            })
        } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
            db.collection("users").doc(auth.user.uid).collection("basket").add({
              id: doc.id,
              quantity: doc.quantity
             })
        }
        })          
    })
    })
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [@Dharmaraj's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13130697/dharmaraj) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68741937/3068190) solves your direct query, by tweaking the way you store the basket, you can eliminate the query and also get rid of the potential for duplicate items in the basket.

The following answer assumes that `result_array` (renamed `items_array` below) is an array of items to be added to the user's basket and `/users/someUserID/basket` is the user's current basket.

You can simplify your code by using the item's ID as the key of the document. This would involve switching out this code:

```js
db
  .collection("users")
  .doc(auth.user.uid)
  .collection("basket")
  .add({
    id: item.id,
    quantity: item.quantity
  });
```

for this:

```js
db
  .collection("users")
  .doc(auth.user.uid)
  .collection("basket")
  .doc(item.id) // <- use the item ID as the document ID
  .set({
    id: item.id, // <- you could remove this if desired
    quantity: item.quantity
  });
```

By making use of an [`increment()` operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value), you can increase the quantity by the requested amount. My using `set()` with `{ merge: true }`, you can create the document if it doesn't exist or update the existing quantity if it does, in a single operation:

```js
db
  .collection("users")
  .doc(auth.user.uid)
  .collection("basket")
  .doc(item.id) // <- use the item ID as the document ID
  .set({
    id: item.id, // <- you could remove this if desired
    quantity: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(item.quantity)
  }, { merge: true }); // <- creates/updates document
```

You can also further optimize your code bringing the reference to the basket out of your for loop.

```js
const userBasketColRef = db
  .collection("users")
  .doc(auth.user.uid)
  .collection("basket");

items_array.forEach(item => {
  userBasketColRef
    .doc(item.id) 
    .set({
      id: item.id,
      quantity: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(item.quantity)
    }, { merge: true })
    .catch(err => {
      // don't forget error handling!
      console.error('Failed to update basket for item #' + item.id, err);
    });
});
```

Lastly, you can swap to using [a batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) to make the changes all-at-once (atomically) and handle errors in the one spot:

```js
const batch = db.batch();
const userBasketColRef = db
  .collection("users")
  .doc(auth.user.uid)
  .collection("basket");

items_array.forEach(item => {
  batch.set(
    userBasketColRef.doc(item.id), // <- use the item ID as the document ID
    {
      id: item.id,
      quantity: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(item.quantity)
    },
    { merge: true }
  );
});

batch.commit()
  .then(() => console.log('Updated basket successfully!'))
  .catch((err) => console.error('Failed to update basket'));
```

Answer (score 2):

A query returns documents that *exactly matches* your condition and that means all the docs returned in the [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) exist. That `if (document.exists)` check in the forEach loop is redundant.

> Are you checking if at least 1 document matched your query?

Try using `.empty` property on the `QuerySnapshot` to check the query has returned any documents:

```js
db.collection("users").doc(auth.user.uid).collection("basket").where( "id" , "==" ,doc.id ).get()
  .then((docs) => {
    if (docs.empty) {
      // console.log("0 documents returned")
    } else {
      // Docs returned 
      console.log(docs.docs.map(d => d.data()))
    }
})
```